# Django Crispy Forms Form Helper - Custom Checkbox CSS Class

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm presently using Django's crispy forms to generate a HTML form.

I would like to change the text of read-only check-boxes to white with an opacity of 0.5.

Looking at the Chrome Developer Console, I see crispy forms is calling the .custom-control-input:disabled~.custom-control-label from https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/scss/_custom-forms.scss.

Within the console I can change it without issue; the problem I face is trying to overwrite the scss class.

Copying the relevant parts of the scss file, I've created a new one in my project:

**.SCSS File:**

```
.mycustom-control {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: ($font-size-base * $line-height-base);
    padding-left: $mycustom-control-gutter;
  }

  .mycustom-control-inline {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-right: $mycustom-control-spacer-x;
  }

  .mycustom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; // Put the input behind the label so it doesn't overlay text
    opacity: 0;

    &:checked ~ .mycustom-control-label::before {
      color: $mycustom-control-indicator-checked-color;
      @include gradient-bg($mycustom-control-indicator-checked-bg);
      @include box-shadow($mycustom-control-indicator-checked-box-shadow);
    }

    &:focus ~ .mycustom-control-label::before {
      // the mixin is not used here to make sure there is feedback
      box-shadow: $mycustom-control-indicator-focus-box-shadow;
    }

    &:active ~ .mycustom-control-label::before {
      color: $mycustom-control-indicator-active-color;
      background-color: $mycustom-control-indicator-active-bg;
      @include box-shadow($mycustom-control-indicator-active-box-shadow);
    }

    &:disabled {
      ~ .mycustom-control-label {
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.5;

        &::before {
          background-color: $mycustom-control-indicator-disabled-bg;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've also loaded it in my **HTML file**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/checkboxes.scss" %}">
```

But how then do I get Django crispy forms to load the custom checkbox?

Within my **Python script** the checkbox is defined as so:

```
computeapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, disabled=True, label='Compute Engine',widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={}))
```

This then is called later in the FormHelper Layout:

```
Fieldset(
        'APIs To Enable',
        Row(
            Column('computeapi', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0', readonly=True),
```

It's within this 'css_class' I'm sure I need to enter the custom checkbox class, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked (and I still need to maintain the form-group column alignment).

My questions are:

1. Is this defined css_class the correct place to call the custom checkbox?
2. What is the correct syntax for calling the checkbox css_class?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `computeapi` is the checkbox (the input field) you shouldn't be trying to apply those classes (`form-group col-md-3 mb-0`) to it, but to its parent. According to [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/), the input field should only have the `form-check-input` class. Disclaimer: I'm not very used to crispy_forms, since I haven't used it anymore from the moment I found [widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/)